# nginx configuration using code

Tags: java, nginx, configuration

I have to update and add different configuration settings to the Nginx config file from java code. Is there easy way to do that if not converting to java objects and writing them back to the file? Is there any github project which have all the method to configure nginx from code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this nginx-java-parser to read, edit and write configuration file.

Link: https://github.com/odiszapc/nginx-java-parser

Example:

```
NgxConfig conf = NgxConfig.read("/etc/nginx/nginx.conf");
NgxParam workers = conf.findParam("worker_processes");       // Ex.1
workers.getValue(); // "1"
NgxParam listen = conf.findParam("http", "server", "listen"); // Ex.2
listen.getValue(); // "8889"
List<NgxEntry> rtmpServers = conf.findAll(NgxConfig.BLOCK, "rtmp", "server"); // Ex.3
for (NgxEntry entry : rtmpServers) {
    ((NgxBlock)entry).getName(); // "server"
    ((NgxBlock)entry).findParam("application", "live"); // "on" for the first iter, "off" for the second one
}
```